# What is the difference between a projection and an orthogonal projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

So in my notes it talked about projecting a vector onto a subspace, but then introduced orthogonal projections. What is the difference? How should I visualize orthogonal projections?

Comment: It is "the Sun anywhere" and "the Sun at its zenith".

Answer (score 0):

Red, orthogonal projection.  Blue, projection.

[image]

Comment: So does the orthogonal projection project the vector so that its orthogonal to the plane.

Comment: Where do you think the adjective "orthogonal" came from!?!

Comment: @DylanDijk Just to clarify, the results of the projections are where those lines meet the orange plane, not the lines themselves. The projection of a vector onto a plane lies on that plane.

Comment: You project a point onto the surface, here orange plane.  Technically "projection" is the action or operation of finding that (projected) point on the surface.  The lines allow us to visualize this mathematical operation.